# Insert the data in MYSQL and also open dialog box when button clicked

Tags: php, jquery, forms

There are two forms involved in my details.php page, i.e. detail-form and dialog form as shown in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qC4WR/1/).

I want to insert the data of "detail-form" in database using MYSQL when a user clicks on "Assign To someone" button. Its been a difficult task for me as it will include both opening of dialog box and inserting the data. So any ideas how can I fire that Insert query??

Below is my code:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   function validatedata()
   {
      ob_start();


// If the form was submitted, scrub the input (server-side validation)
// see below in the html for the client-side validation using jQuery
      $name= '';
      $clname = '';
      $clemail= '';

// collect all input and trim to remove leading and trailing whitespaces
      $name = trim($_POST['name']);
      $clname = trim($_POST['client_name']);
      $clemail= trim($_POST['client_email']);
      $errors = array();

      if (strlen($name) < 2 && (!filter_var($name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
      array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/[a-zA-Z ]/")))) )
               array_push($errors, "Please enter a name. Name must contain at least 2 characters");

      if (strlen($clname) < 2 && (!filter_var($clname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
      array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/[a-zA-Z ]/")))) )
               array_push($errors, "Please enter a name. Name must contain at least 2 characters");

      if (!filter_var($clemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
               array_push($errors, "Please specify a valid email address");

// If no errors were found, proceed with storing the user input
      if (count($errors) == 0) 
      {
               array_push($errors, "No errors were found. Thanks!");
      }

//Prepare errors for output
      $output = '';
      foreach($errors as $val) {
               $output .= "<p class='output'>$val</p>";
          }

   }  


function insert_data()
{ 

$name= $_POST['name'];
$client_name= $_POST['client_name'];
$client_email= $_POST['client_email'];


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db"); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Client_details`(`name`, `client_name`, `email`)  VALUES ('$name','$client_name','$client_email')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));


}


 if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
validatedata();
insert_data();
header("location:sections.php");
exit;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire ajax post when you click assign button like;

```
$("#Assign").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: your_url,
      data: $("#detail-form").serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        //handle response
      }
    });
});
```

You can see your updated fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/qC4WR/3/**

Comment: I can't see my dialog box opening now and data are also not getting inserted.

Comment: Check updated fiddle. And be sure that you have updated specific fields on example ajax call